# Web View crashes tabbed application when changing tab?

Tags: ios, swift, web

I am trying to create an app with three tabs. I have the ViewControllers all setup and working, however when I try to run a Web View on any of the different tabs, other than the fist, it crashes with a message like this:

```
2016-10-06 23:17:54.565932 Techaway[6827:2354958] Unknown class ThirdViewController in Interface Builder file.
2016-10-06 23:17:59.520639 Techaway[6827:2354958] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Techaway.SecondViewController 0x100f0bc20> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Home.'
```

It works perfectly if in the first ViewController though, which confuses me.

Example of the code in SecondViewController:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var url = URL(string: "https://example.com/")!

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    @IBAction func home(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))


}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

I just don't understand why it works in one place but not another!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a bad connection in your xib. so you need to delete not referenced IBOutlet form UIViewController in storyboard or xib .

More about this refer following link : 
[What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: … this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v)